# tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn - 'Tensor' object is not iterable

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

Here is an attempt to set up simple RNN:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

BATCH_SIZE = 7 
SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 5
VECTOR_SIZE = 3
STATE_SIZE = 4

x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [BATCH_SIZE, SEQUENCE_LENGTH, VECTOR_SIZE],
                   name='input_placeholder')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [BATCH_SIZE, SEQUENCE_LENGTH,],
                   name='labels_placeholder')
init_state = tf.zeros([BATCH_SIZE, STATE_SIZE])

rnn_inputs = tf.unstack(x, axis = 1)
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(STATE_SIZE, state_is_tuple = True)
rnn_outputs, final_state = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(cell, rnn_inputs, initial_state=init_state)
```

It troughs the following error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-cf3e657dfb23> in <module>()
     13 cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(STATE_SIZE, state_is_tuple = True)
     14 #rnn_outputs, final_state = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(cell, rnn_inputs, initial_state=init_state)
---> 15 results__ = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(cell, rnn_inputs, initial_state=init_state)

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py in static_rnn(cell, inputs, initial_state, dtype, sequence_length, scope)
   1235             state_size=cell.state_size)
   1236       else:
-> 1237         (output, state) = call_cell()
   1238 
   1239       outputs.append(output)

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py in <lambda>()
   1222         varscope.reuse_variables()
   1223       # pylint: disable=cell-var-from-loop
-> 1224       call_cell = lambda: cell(input_, state)
   1225       # pylint: enable=cell-var-from-loop
   1226       if sequence_length is not None:

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn_cell_impl.py in __call__(self, inputs, state, scope)
    178       with vs.variable_scope(vs.get_variable_scope(),
    179                              custom_getter=self._rnn_get_variable):
--> 180         return super(RNNCell, self).__call__(inputs, state)
    181 
    182   def _rnn_get_variable(self, getter, *args, **kwargs):

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\layers\base.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    448         # Check input assumptions set after layer building, e.g. input shape.
    449         self._assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
--> 450         outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    451 
    452         # Apply activity regularization.

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn_cell_impl.py in call(self, inputs, state)
    395     # Parameters of gates are concatenated into one multiply for efficiency.
    396     if self._state_is_tuple:
--> 397       c, h = state
    398     else:
    399       c, h = array_ops.split(value=state, num_or_size_splits=2, axis=1)

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in __iter__(self)
    474       TypeError: when invoked.
    475     """
--> 476     raise TypeError("'Tensor' object is not iterable.")
    477 
    478   def __bool__(self):

TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable.
```

I am not sure why it produces this error. There are multiple posts like this on SO, but they do not answer the question.

**UPDATE**

Here is what I tried after Aaron answer:

```py
BATCH_SIZE = 7 
SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 5
VECTOR_SIZE = 3
STATE_SIZE = 4

x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [BATCH_SIZE, SEQUENCE_LENGTH, VECTOR_SIZE],
                   name='input_placeholder')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [BATCH_SIZE, SEQUENCE_LENGTH,],
                   name='labels_placeholder')
init_state_state = tf.zeros([BATCH_SIZE, STATE_SIZE], tf.int32)
init_state_input = tf.zeros([BATCH_SIZE, VECTOR_SIZE], tf.int32)

rnn_inputs = tf.unstack(x, axis = 1)
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(STATE_SIZE, state_is_tuple = True)
rnn_outputs, final_state = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(cell, rnn_inputs, initial_state=(init_state_state, init_state_input))
```

Now I have the following error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-79fd4965953c> in <module>()
     14 rnn_inputs = tf.unstack(x, axis = 1)
     15 cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(STATE_SIZE, state_is_tuple = True)
---> 16 rnn_outputs, final_state = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(cell, rnn_inputs, initial_state=(init_state_state, init_state_input))

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py in static_rnn(cell, inputs, initial_state, dtype, sequence_length, scope)
   1235             state_size=cell.state_size)
   1236       else:
-> 1237         (output, state) = call_cell()
   1238 
   1239       outputs.append(output)

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py in <lambda>()
   1222         varscope.reuse_variables()
   1223       # pylint: disable=cell-var-from-loop
-> 1224       call_cell = lambda: cell(input_, state)
   1225       # pylint: enable=cell-var-from-loop
   1226       if sequence_length is not None:

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn_cell_impl.py in __call__(self, inputs, state, scope)
    178       with vs.variable_scope(vs.get_variable_scope(),
    179                              custom_getter=self._rnn_get_variable):
--> 180         return super(RNNCell, self).__call__(inputs, state)
    181 
    182   def _rnn_get_variable(self, getter, *args, **kwargs):

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\layers\base.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    448         # Check input assumptions set after layer building, e.g. input shape.
    449         self._assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
--> 450         outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    451 
    452         # Apply activity regularization.

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn_cell_impl.py in call(self, inputs, state)
    399       c, h = array_ops.split(value=state, num_or_size_splits=2, axis=1)
    400 
--> 401     concat = _linear([inputs, h], 4 * self._num_units, True)
    402 
    403     # i = input_gate, j = new_input, f = forget_gate, o = output_gate

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn_cell_impl.py in _linear(args, output_size, bias, bias_initializer, kernel_initializer)
   1051           _BIAS_VARIABLE_NAME, [output_size],
   1052           dtype=dtype,
-> 1053           initializer=bias_initializer)
   1054     return nn_ops.bias_add(res, biases)

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py in get_variable(name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer, trainable, collections, caching_device, partitioner, validate_shape, use_resource, custom_getter)
   1063       collections=collections, caching_device=caching_device,
   1064       partitioner=partitioner, validate_shape=validate_shape,
-> 1065       use_resource=use_resource, custom_getter=custom_getter)
   1066 get_variable_or_local_docstring = (
   1067     """%s

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py in get_variable(self, var_store, name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer, reuse, trainable, collections, caching_device, partitioner, validate_shape, use_resource, custom_getter)
    960           collections=collections, caching_device=caching_device,
    961           partitioner=partitioner, validate_shape=validate_shape,
--> 962           use_resource=use_resource, custom_getter=custom_getter)
    963 
    964   def _get_partitioned_variable(self,

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py in get_variable(self, name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer, reuse, trainable, collections, caching_device, partitioner, validate_shape, use_resource, custom_getter)
    358           reuse=reuse, trainable=trainable, collections=collections,
    359           caching_device=caching_device, partitioner=partitioner,
--> 360           validate_shape=validate_shape, use_resource=use_resource)
    361     else:
    362       return _true_getter(

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn_cell_impl.py in _rnn_get_variable(self, getter, *args, **kwargs)
    181 
    182   def _rnn_get_variable(self, getter, *args, **kwargs):
--> 183     variable = getter(*args, **kwargs)
    184     trainable = (variable in tf_variables.trainable_variables() or
    185                  (isinstance(variable, tf_variables.PartitionedVariable) and

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py in _true_getter(name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer, reuse, trainable, collections, caching_device, partitioner, validate_shape, use_resource)
    350           trainable=trainable, collections=collections,
    351           caching_device=caching_device, validate_shape=validate_shape,
--> 352           use_resource=use_resource)
    353 
    354     if custom_getter is not None:

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py in _get_single_variable(self, name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer, partition_info, reuse, trainable, collections, caching_device, validate_shape, use_resource)
    723           caching_device=caching_device,
    724           dtype=variable_dtype,
--> 725           validate_shape=validate_shape)
    726     self._vars[name] = v
    727     logging.vlog(1, "Created variable %s with shape %s and init %s", v.name,

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py in __init__(self, initial_value, trainable, collections, validate_shape, caching_device, name, variable_def, dtype, expected_shape, import_scope)
    197           name=name,
    198           dtype=dtype,
--> 199           expected_shape=expected_shape)
    200 
    201   def __repr__(self):

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py in _init_from_args(self, initial_value, trainable, collections, validate_shape, caching_device, name, dtype, expected_shape)
    275             with ops.name_scope("Initializer"),  ops.device(None):
    276               self._initial_value = ops.convert_to_tensor(
--> 277                   initial_value(), name="initial_value", dtype=dtype)
    278               shape = (self._initial_value.get_shape()
    279                        if validate_shape else tensor_shape.unknown_shape())

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py in <lambda>()
    699           initializer = initializer(dtype=dtype)
    700         init_val = lambda: initializer(  # pylint: disable=g-long-lambda
--> 701             shape.as_list(), dtype=dtype, partition_info=partition_info)
    702         variable_dtype = dtype.base_dtype
    703 

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\init_ops.py in __call__(self, shape, dtype, partition_info, verify_shape)
    201       verify_shape = self._verify_shape
    202     return constant_op.constant(self.value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape,
--> 203                                 verify_shape=verify_shape)
    204 
    205   def get_config(self):

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape)
    100   tensor_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue()
    101   tensor_value.tensor.CopyFrom(
--> 102       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
    103   dtype_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=tensor_value.tensor.dtype)
    104   const_tensor = g.create_op(

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    374       nparray = np.empty(shape, dtype=np_dt)
    375     else:
--> 376       _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
    377       nparray = np.array(values, dtype=np_dt)
    378       # check to them.

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py in _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
    300     else:
    301       raise TypeError("Expected %s, got %s of type '%s' instead." %
--> 302                       (dtype.name, repr(mismatch), type(mismatch).__name__))
    303 
    304 

TypeError: Expected int32, got 0.0 of type 'float' instead.
```

Sorry for another update, but after switching to float32, I get another error:

```py
BATCH_SIZE = 7 
SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 5
VECTOR_SIZE = 3
STATE_SIZE = 4

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [BATCH_SIZE, SEQUENCE_LENGTH, VECTOR_SIZE],
                   name='input_placeholder')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [BATCH_SIZE, SEQUENCE_LENGTH,],
                   name='labels_placeholder')
init_state_state = tf.zeros([BATCH_SIZE, STATE_SIZE], tf.float32)
init_state_input = tf.zeros([BATCH_SIZE, VECTOR_SIZE], tf.float32)

rnn_inputs = tf.unstack(x, axis = 1)
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(STATE_SIZE, state_is_tuple = True)
rnn_outputs, final_state = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(cell, rnn_inputs, initial_state=(init_state_state, init_state_input))
```

Here is final line of the error message:

```py
ValueError: Trying to share variable rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel, but specified shape (7, 16) and found shape (6, 16).
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because your LSTM init state should be a tuple and you are giving it only a single vector of zeros. Make the init state be a tuple of two zero vectors and you should be fine.

In a simple RNN or in a GRU there is only one vector for the state. LSTMs have two vectors in the state.

Comment: Overall, why initial state needs to be a tuple? From whatever architectures I have see, current input and previous state is what we feed into cell. In first cell we have no previous state, so it is reasonable to feed zeros, but we do have actual input.

Comment: Look at your error message. You have ints instead of floats

Comment: Ok, I guess I found solution. Tuple should contain same size tensors, but why it is so, it is unclear. Lack of clarity makes me want to use manual iteration.